# SourceTree is Deleting Files when Staging Changes

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

Recently I've been having an issue with SourceTree deleting files when I stage changes. For example, I add a comment to a file shown in the following screenshot:

[image: unstaged change - showing correctly]

But once I click on the 'stage' button, SourceTree seems to remove the file completely as in this screenshot:

[image: staged change - file is removed]

It's worth noting that this does not seem to happen for every file, just some. Solutions I have tried:

1. Uninstalling/reinstalling SourceTree
2. Deleting SourceTree prefs from %AppData%/local

Does anyone have any idea what may be happening? Thank you so much for any and all help!

Comment: "But once I click on the 'stage' button" What button do you mean?

Comment: Also, what platform are you on? That is not what my Sourcetree interface looks like.

Comment: I'm on Windows. And I meant the "Stage All" button near the bottom of the first picture.

If I run 'git add .' in the git terminal, it works correctly, but if I do it via that "Stage All" button it seems to mess things up like in the above screenshots.

Comment: It sure sounds like a bug in the Windows version of Sourcetree! Sorry this is happening, but if it were me, I'd stop using it and report the bug. Find another GUI, or just use the command line.

Comment: Oh by the way! Sourcetree records every Git command it emits. So if this does happen again you can look directly and see whether Sourcetree said `git rm` or something.

Answer (score 0):

What helped me was deleting the repo from SourceTree and re-adding it.
Steps:

- Click on the + sign (shows local repositories)
- Right click on the problematic repo
- Delete
- Select 'Remove Bookmarks'
- Re-add the repo